# ng-switchery doesn't update on $http callback

Tags: angularjs, http, checkbox, angularjs-directive, callback

I've got a checkbox using ng-switchery which looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="pull-right js-switch" ui-switch="{color:'#1AB394'}" ng-model="activeSwitch"/>
```

In my the controller that handles this I'm fetching some data using $http :

```
$http.get('/clients/' + $stateParams.id)
            .success(function (client) {
                $scope.client = client;
                $scope.activeSwitch = $scope.client.active;
            });
```

I would expect the callback to successfully set the state of my checkbox aswell, but it doesn't. I have tried calling `$scope.$apply()` but that didn't really change anything, neither did adding an `ng-checked` directive on the checkbox.

Comment: @Rebornix this is the entire code...

Comment: @Rebornix Hear that? All you have to do is turn on the V8 JS parser in your brain and run the app in your frontal cortex.

Comment: @DanMoldovan, there is not enough code here to see the issue. Perhaps it is with the data. I agree with others - replicate in a plunker instead of asking others to do this for you.

Comment: @DanMoldovan agreed with ^^^.  You haven't provided enough information to get an answer.  Questions: are you able to change other items in the view using $scope (ie. are things hooked up correctly).  What is the value of $scope.client.active?  Have you confirmed it is `true`?  Also, note that you shouldn't put $http calls in your controllers - these should be moved into services.

Answer (score 1):

All I have to say is that this was ALL the code. There was nothing more. So here's the solution:

Apparently this isn't an Angular problem, but rather ng-switchery just doesn't want to reload properly when activeSwitch changes, as such by adding an ng-if, it will be forced to only be on the DOM when activeSwitch exists, as in when http has executed its callback

```
<input ng-if="activeSwitch!==undefined" type="checkbox" class="pull-right js-switch" ui-switch="{color:'#1AB394'}" ng-model="activeSwitch"/>
```

This solution works. Thanks for all of your "constructive" answers